# The endpoint for my Azure APIs (Translator Text, Computer Vision) is not accesible (error code 404)

Tags: c#, azure, hololens

I followed the Hololens Tutorials provided by Microsoft and encountered some problems regarding Azure services in 301 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mr-azure-301#chapter-4--setup-debug-canvas) and 302 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mr-azure-302). I think the problem has something to do with the endpoint, because the error code 404 appears when checking https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/.

I use the Hololens first generation, Unity 2017.4.27f1, HoloToolkit-Unity-Examples-2017.4.3.0 and Visual Studio Community 2017. I've tried some of the Hololens tutorials, which all worked fine with these versions. My code is the one provided by Microsoft for the Tutorials 301 and 302. I've changed the location in Azure from 
'global' to 'Western Europe' by creating a new ressource group and have now https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/ as my endpoint, I also created new authentification keys for the APIs and updated them in my code.

Instead of myKey I inserted the first key of the respective API (Translator Text, Computer Vision). The code below is from Tutorial 302 and the class 'VisionManager.cs' (which seems to be the responsible one for the communication with the services of the Computer Vision API).

```
public static VisionManager instance;

// you must insert your service key here!    
private string authorizationKey = "myKey";
private const string ocpApimSubscriptionKeyHeader = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key";
private string visionAnalysisEndpoint = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0";   // This is where you need to update your endpoint, if you set your location to something other than west-us.

internal byte[] imageBytes;

internal string imagePath;

/// <summary>
/// Call the Computer Vision Service to submit the image.
/// </summary>
public IEnumerator AnalyseLastImageCaptured()
{
    WWWForm webForm = new WWWForm();
    using (UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(visionAnalysisEndpoint, webForm))
    {
        // gets a byte array out of the saved image
        imageBytes = GetImageAsByteArray(imagePath);
        unityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        unityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader(ocpApimSubscriptionKeyHeader, authorizationKey);

        // the download handler will help receiving the analysis from Azure
        unityWebRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

        // the upload handler will help uploading the byte array with the request
        unityWebRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(imageBytes);
        unityWebRequest.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/octet-stream";

        yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();

        long responseCode = unityWebRequest.responseCode;

        try
        {
            string jsonResponse = null;
            jsonResponse = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text;

            // The response will be in Json format
            // therefore it needs to be deserialized into the classes AnalysedObject and TagData
            AnalysedObject analysedObject = new AnalysedObject();
            analysedObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<AnalysedObject>(jsonResponse);

            if (analysedObject.tags == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("analysedObject.tagData is null");
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, float> tagsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, float>();

                foreach (TagData td in analysedObject.tags)
                {
                    TagData tag = td as TagData;
                    tagsDictionary.Add(tag.name, tag.confidence);
                }

                ResultsLabel.instance.SetTagsToLastLabel(tagsDictionary);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.Log("Json exception.Message: " + exception.Message);
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TagData
{
    public string name;
    public float confidence;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class AnalysedObject
{
    public TagData[] tags;
    public string requestId;
    public object metadata;
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

private void Awake()
{
    // allows this instance to behave like a singleton
    instance = this;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the contents of the specified file as a byte array.
/// </summary>
private static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
    return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
}
```

I expected the output to be like the examples in the tutorials, but instead I got the same GUI results without any updates. In 301 I could see the same screen, but the text field 'You just said' and the 'Translation' never updated when I spoke. In 302 I could airtap and make a screenshot and could see at first 'Analyzing' and later on 'I see:' but without any results of detected objects. So it seems to me, that the Azure APIs services can't be contacted and I don't get any analysis data in return (probably you notice, that I'm quite new to the whole topic, so maybe my assumption is wrong).